# Is there a screen sharing package of Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a screen sharing application (iOS / Android) without full control. Just share their screens, like screen sharing in Skype.

Does anyone know how to use Screen sharing with flutter?
Do I have to use native code?
Or can I use agora.io SDK for this purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate more? i.e. you want to create a remote desktop kind of application. where one user can access another user mobile screen? with full control?

Comment: I just added more details :)

Comment: As per my knowledge, there is no flutter package. You might have to use android and iOS native code. or if you can find the android, iOS native library. and write a dart wrapper around it to use it with flutter.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this @Jun

Comment: Is there anyone find solutions ?

Comment: @MasahiroAoki any Solution?

Comment: I found this.
https://connectycube.com/2022/01/06/meet-screen-sharing-support-in-connectycube-flutter-sdk/

Answer (score 1):

Agora SDK does seem to be capable of screen sharing. However, Agora's Flutter SDK needs to use [Platform Views](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-views) so you'll be required to use platform-specific code. You can follow the guide shared in [this thread](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Agora-Flutter-SDK/issues/109#issuecomment-612616359) for more details on screen sharing using Agora SDK on iOS and Android with Flutter.